# How to enable a form for given period

Tags: php, symfony-3.2

I have to create a form that can be enabled and disabled by the admin,
In my case the admin enable the form for two months per year(to be filled by users) a sort of survey.

The admin provide start date and end date ,if the Current date is in the periode given the form is enabled  for all of users else a message “form unavailable”appears.

The form contain a lot of information ,those data will be stored in the database on multiple tables.

How can I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods for doing what you want. One way is to access the current timestamp using the `time()` function and running it through an if statement for checking the set dates,

```
<?php
$sDate = 1494354600;
$eDate = 1499625000;
$cDate = time();
if($cDate>$sDate&&$cDate<$eDate){
   <Form code here>
}
else{
   echo "Form Unavailable";
}
?>
```

`sDate` is the timestamp of date from which the form will be available, `eDate` is the date till which form will be available and `cDate` is the current date.

This code will make the form available from 10/05/2017 to 10/07/2017 [DD/MM/YYYY].

You can convert date to timestamp by using some website which you can find in a Google search.

Hope this helped.